# Side scroll mobile tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I am trying to create a dropdown menu in a bootstrap site that has tabs in it. The icons go further than the width of the menu and I would like mobile users to be able to side scroll it.

Here is a link to it.

https://jsfiddle.net/6yw6rp02/1/

This is the code I am using.

```
<div class="top-nav-mobile">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="top-nav-btns">

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#asdf" aria-controls="asdf" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#asdf" aria-controls="asdf" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-signal"></i></a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#asdf" aria-controls="asdf" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#asdf" aria-controls="asdf" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-bell"></i></a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#asdf" aria-controls="asdf" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#asdf" aria-controls="asdf" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-money"></i></a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#asdf" aria-controls="asdf" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-bug"></i></a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#asdf" aria-controls="asdf" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-wheelchair"></i></a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#asdf" aria-controls="asdf" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#asdf" aria-controls="asdf" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="fa fa-bug"></i></a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="asdf">

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried using owl carousel, but I cant seem to get it to work without choosing an amount of items which I dont exactly want to do.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to be able to scroll in it in mobile the easiest way is just to add a scrollbar and hide it so you are able to scroll through the menu but without having a real scrollbar shown (or if you prefer you could leave it its up to you :)

Here is what i have tried ->

```
.top-nav-mobile .top-nav-btns {
    width: 280px;
    overflow: auto;

}
.top-nav-mobile .nav li {
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     display:inline-block;
     float:none;
     margin-right:-4px;
}
.top-nav-mobile .nav-tabs {
    border-bottom: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

*this adds the scrollbar and scrolling functionallity (we remove the set width so it ll work for as many as you want elements, the negative margin is for removing the white space that inline-block elements create AND the white-space:nowrap actually makes it to be on one expandable line  :)

```
.top-nav-mobile .top-nav-btns::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 0 !important; }
```

*this hides it (if you want you could skip it)

This is the working JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/6yw6rp02/4/
I hope i helped you :)